# SQL: Sum Only Certain Rows Depending on Start and End Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have two tables: The 1st table contains a unique identifier (UI). Each unique identifier has a column containing a start date (yyyy-mm-dd), and a column containing an end date (yyyy-mm-dd). The 2nd table contains the temperature for each day, with separate columns for the month, day, year and temperature. I would like to join those tables and get the compiled temperature for each unique identifier; however I would the compiled temperature to only include the days from the second table that fall between start and end dates from the 1st table. 
For example, if one record has a start_date of 12/10/15 and an end date of 12/31/15, I would like to have a column containing compiled temperatures for the 10th-31s. If the next record has a start date 12/3/15-12/17/15, I'd like the column next to it to show the compiled temperature for the 3rd-17th. I'll include the query I have so far, but it is not too helpful because I have not really gotten very far:

```
; with Temps as (
    select MONTH, DAY, YEAR, Temp
    from Temperatures
    where MONTH = 12
    and YEAR = 2016
    )
    Select UI, start_date, end_date, location, SUM(temp)
    from Table1 t1
    Inner join Temps
    on temps.month = month(t1.start_date)
```

I appreciate any help you might be able to give. Let me know I need to elaborate on anything.

```
Table 1     
UI  Start_Date  End_Date
2080    12/5/2015   12/31/2015
1266    12/1/2015   12/31/2015
1787    12/17/2015  12/28/2015
1621    12/3/2015   12/20/2015
1974    12/10/2015  12/12/2015
1731    12/25/2015  12/31/2015


Table 2         
    Month   Day Year    Temp
    12  1   2016    34
    12  2   2016    32
    12  3   2016    35
    12  4   2016    37
    12  5   2016    32
    12  6   2016    30
    12  7   2016    31
    12  8   2016    36
    12  9   2016    48
    12  10  2016    42
    12  11  2016    33
    12  12  2016    41
    12  13  2016    31
    12  14  2016    29
    12  15  2016    46
    12  16  2016    48
    12  17  2016    38
    12  18  2016    29
    12  19  2016    45
    12  20  2016    37
    12  21  2016    48
    12  22  2016    46
    12  23  2016    44
    12  24  2016    45
    12  25  2016    35
    12  26  2016    44
    12  27  2016    29
    12  28  2016    38
    12  29  2016    29
    12  30  2016    35
    12  31  2016    40

Table 3 (Expected Result)           
UI  Start_Date  End_Date    Compiled Temp
2080    12/5/2015   12/31/2015  1101
1266    12/1/2015   12/31/2015  1167
1787    12/17/2015  12/28/2015  478
1621    12/3/2015   12/20/2015  668
1974    12/10/2015  12/12/2015  126
1731    12/25/2015  12/31/2015  250
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample dataset for each table and and example of expected/desired output?  A picture truly is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Are you sure you want compiled temps and not averaged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
; WITH temps AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(4), [YEAR]) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), [MONTH]) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), [DAY])) [TDate], [Temp]
    FROM Temperatures
    WHERE [MONTH] = 12
    AND [YEAR] = 2015
    ) 
    SELECT [UI], [start_date], [end_date]
        , (SELECT SUM([temp]) 
        FROM temps
        WHERE [TDate] BETWEEN T1.[start_date] AND T1.[end_date]) [Compiled Temp]
    FROM Table1 T1
```

No need for a join.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple join of the two tables as well.  You don't need to use a CTE.

```
--TEST DATA
if object_id('Table1','U') is not null
    drop table Table1

create table Table1 (UI int, Start_Date date, End_Date date)     

insert Table1
values
(2080,'12/05/2015','12/31/2015'),
(1266,'12/01/2015','12/31/2015'),
(1787,'12/17/2015','12/28/2015'),
(1621,'12/03/2015','12/20/2015'),
(1974,'12/10/2015','12/12/2015'),
(1731,'12/25/2015','12/31/2015')

if object_id('Table2','U') is not null
    drop table Table2

create table Table2 (Month int, Day int, Year int, Temp int)     

insert Table2
values
(12,1, 2015,34),
(12,2, 2015,32),
(12,3, 2015,35),
(12,4, 2015,37),
(12,5, 2015,32),
(12,6, 2015,30),
(12,7, 2015,31),
(12,8, 2015,36),
(12,9, 2015,48),
(12,10,2015,42),
(12,11,2015,33),
(12,12,2015,41),
(12,13,2015,31),
(12,14,2015,29),
(12,15,2015,46),
(12,16,2015,48),
(12,17,2015,38),
(12,18,2015,29),
(12,19,2015,45),
(12,20,2015,37),
(12,21,2015,48),
(12,22,2015,46),
(12,23,2015,44),
(12,24,2015,45),
(12,25,2015,35),
(12,26,2015,44)


--AGGREGATE TEMPS
select t1.Start_Date, t1.End_Date, avg(t2.temp) AvgTemp, sum(t2.temp) CompiledTemps
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 ON t2.Year between datepart(year, t1.Start_Date) and datepart(year, t1.End_Date)
        and t2.Month          between datepart(month,t1.Start_Date) and datepart(month,t1.End_Date)
        and t2.Day            between datepart(day,  t1.Start_Date) and datepart(day,  t1.End_Date)
group by t1.Start_Date, t1.End_Date
```